# Count duplicate values that share same FK id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to Count how many duplicates there are in one column that share the same FK id. There should only be one type per Shared_FK_id.

```
table:
Shared_FK_ID : bigint
type: varchar(50)
```

Sample data:

```
831 Ford
831 Fiat
831 Honda
831 Honda
831 Dodge
831 Volvo
831 Volvo
831 Opel
```

Comment: Please explain what *you* mean by duplicate.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: By duplicate I mean values that are the same in the `type` column.

Comment: In your sample data, what is your expected result?

Comment: Looks a bit obvious but SELECT count(1), type group by type

Comment: "There should only be one type per Shared_FK_id." Do you really mean "There should only be one **instance of each type** per Shared_FK_id."?

Comment: Your right. yes I did

Comment: And do you want the total number of duplicated rows in the whole FK ID, or the number of types which contain duplicates? or the number of duplicates within each type?  I guess one of these queries would suit you, depending on the precise output you want: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c8e1ed9607430fde16157367d59afc90

Comment: P.S. If you actually meant what I suggested, then please edit your question appropriately, so it's clear for everyone.

Comment: One of your suggestions from the link worked. make a solution suggestion and I will accept the answer.

Comment: I can do...if you first tell me which one was the solution you wanted :-)

Comment: The two last examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on [Serg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56360201/5947043), and also make it SQL-Server specific, you can do either of the following depending on exactly what output you need.

1)  the number of types which contain duplicates:

```
select Shared_FK_ID, count(*) nmbr_of_dbls
from (
   select Shared_FK_ID, [type] , count(*) nmbr
   from data
   group by Shared_FK_ID, [type]
   having count(*) > 1
) t
group by Shared_FK_ID
```

2) the total number of duplicated rows in the whole FK ID:

```
select Shared_FK_ID, sum(nmbr) nmbr_of_dbls
from (
   select Shared_FK_ID, [type] , count(*) nmbr
   from data
   group by Shared_FK_ID, [type]
   having count(*) > 1
) t
group by Shared_FK_ID
```

live demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c8e1ed9607430fde16157367d59afc90

Answer (score 2):

Should work for most sql DBMSes

```
  select Shared_FK_ID, count(*) nmbr_of_dbls
    from (
       select Shared_FK_ID, type , count(*)
       group by Shared_FK_ID, type
       having count(*) > 1
    ) t
  group by Shared_FK_ID
```